Text spacing does not match when drawing text on TreeView
My project is a winforms app, using .Net Framework 4.8.
I have been having a graphical issue in which TreeViews with the same font and text are being drawn differently. On one TreeView, I need to draw a custom highlight when the node is selected, which (I believe) means I need to set the DrawMode property to TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText and attach a handler to the TreeView.DrawNode event to draw the box. However, this has the side effect of making the text on this view appear differently than the other. I eventually discovered that the text is drawn differently even if the DrawNode event handler does nothing but set the DrawTreeNodeEventArgs.DrawDefault property to true.
I have created a minimal reproduction of this issue:

/* Form1.Designer.cs */
partial class Form1 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing && (components != null)) {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.treeView_normal = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
        this.treeView_owner = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // treeView_normal
        // 
        this.treeView_normal.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
        this.treeView_normal.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Inconsolata Condensed", 15.85714F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.treeView_normal.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.treeView_normal.Name = "treeView_normal";
        this.treeView_normal.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(725, 831);
        this.treeView_normal.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // treeView_owner
        // 
        this.treeView_owner.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
        this.treeView_owner.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Inconsolata Condensed", 15.85714F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.treeView_owner.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(777, 0);
        this.treeView_owner.Name = "treeView_owner";
        this.treeView_owner.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(690, 831);
        this.treeView_owner.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(11F, 24F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1467, 831);
        this.Controls.Add(this.treeView_owner);
        this.Controls.Add(this.treeView_normal);
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TreeView treeView_normal;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TreeView treeView_owner;
}
/*********************/


/* Form1.cs */
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        treeView_normal.Size = new Size(400, 450);

        treeView_owner.Location = new Point(408, 0);
        treeView_owner.Size = new Size(400, 450);

        // add some items to both views
        populate(treeView_normal);
        populate(treeView_owner);
        
        // we draw the text of one of the views
        treeView_owner.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
        treeView_owner.DrawNode += TreeFiles_DrawNode;
    }

    private void TreeFiles_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) {
        // draw it the normal way
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }

    private void populate(TreeView treeView) {
        treeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Inconsolata Condensed"));
        treeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Is the font for both of these views"));
        treeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Why is it not the same spacing"));
    }
}

This is how the form is rendered. As you can see the text spacing is noticeably different, with the 'owner drawn' view having much wider text spacing

No matter what I have tried, I am unable to make the text render the same way on both TreeViews, and it looks very wonky especially with longer text.
Here is my more fleshed out attempt, in which I actually draw the highlight rectangle and attempt to use TextRenderer to draw the text:
    private void TreeFiles_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) {
        Color textColor = Color.Black;
        Color backColor = e.Node.BackColor == Color.Empty ? Color.White : e.Node.BackColor;

        if (e.State.HasFlag(TreeNodeStates.Selected) || e.State.HasFlag(TreeNodeStates.Focused)) {
            backColor = Color.LightGray;
        }
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(backColor)) {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
        }
        int drawingPosition = e.Node.Bounds.X;
        RenderNodeText(e.Node.Text, e, (sender as TreeView).Font, new Point(drawingPosition, e.Node.Bounds.Y), textColor);
    }

    private void RenderNodeText(string text, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e, Font font, Point offset, Color foreColor) {
        TextFormatFlags twFormat = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.NoClipping | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding;

        var size = e.Node.Bounds.Size;
        var rect = new Rectangle(offset, size);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, font, rect, foreColor, e.Node.BackColor, twFormat);
    }

Which results in the following, same spacing issue:

Any suggestions on how I can get the text to match? There are other controls that I am trying to match as well, so rendering both with TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText is not a solution.

You could make them look the same by drawing them both manually.... at least that would be consistent.

@JeremyLakeman considered that, but there are other controls on the form with the same font, so it still looks odd

Since you've taken the more fleshed out thing from here, you should mention that -- The Font you're using is probably not a True Type Font, so you most probably cannot use it in the Designer. If you could, you would have noticed that 16 is not a size that can be set directly. It would be, quite probably, 15.75. Since you setup the Font size to a size that is different from what the Win32 TreeView actually uses, you're forcing the creation of a graphic context that's slightly different from the original, which affects the rendering


You should not have using (font) { } there, that Font is not meant to be disposed of in the process + The original code is meant to render a line of text with Fonts of different weights and glue the parts together seamlessly. So, you don't actually need to measure stuff here --Add TextFormatFlags.NoPadding to the flags


@Jimi the font is usable in the designer and I was able to set it to pt size16 in the designer properties menu.

@Jimi ah I see what you mean about the size I think. If I set it in the [...] menu of the font property, it changes to 15.8571434. However, I made changes to use the font as it is set in the designer and added the NoPadding flag and still it has different spacing

also, in the first rendering, where I do nothing but set e.DrawDefault = true;, I don't understand why it draws the text differently. Shouldn't it draw the exact same as the normal TreeView?

No, because you have modified the rendering mode. This causes the .NET implementation to generate a graphics object to handle the drawing -- As described, set the Font size to 15.75, that's the normalized measure of the Font that's closer to 16 -- To have consistent results, your application must be DpiAware and you need to design it at 100% scale. Then test different scales modifying the System's settings, related to Font scaling here

@Jimi ah reopening visual studio with 100% scaling fixed it. Thank you! I don't think I ever would have figured that out.

@Jimi followup question - you said 15.75 is the normalized measure of the font; how would I determine this for myself? What if I wanted to figure out what to use for font size 14, for example? Thanks for the help

The Font measure is generated when converting from the provided measure in the specified Units and the pixels used in a defined Device Context (could be the Screen's DC, the Printer's etc.). You can read the notes here: Properly draw text using GraphicsPath. See also the linked documentation. Win32 Controls use their own logic, to generate the same result across different implementations of the different Controls (which relates to what is described there)

Also quite related to the former, could be useful for testing: How to set the SelectedValue of a ComboBox used as Font selector? --Also to note that you can draw text using Fonts that are not directly supported by the WinForm's Designer (it has never been updated in this department)
